How to set separate colors in GDI+ Color?
GDI+ Color class has functions Get* which return the values of specific colors and alpha channel (like GetR and GetRed; two of them for the same thing!) and at the same time lacks functions Set for separate channels. Only SetValue type functions exist which set all the components at once which is not quite convenient.
Of course, I can always write
inline void SetAlpha(Color& color, BYTE alpha) {
    color.SetValue(Color::MakeARGB(alpha, color.GetR(), color.GetG(), color.GetB()));
}

and the same for other Color components, but am I missing some straightforward way to access the Color components?
If not, what could be the reason of such a design? Is this a kind of compatibility or performance considerations?
Update
It seems that it somehow follows the design decision from GDI where we have only
#define RGB(r,g,b)          ((COLORREF)(((BYTE)(r)|((WORD)((BYTE)(g))<<8))|(((DWORD)(BYTE)(b))<<16)))

#define GetRValue(rgb)      (LOBYTE(rgb))
#define GetGValue(rgb)      (LOBYTE(((WORD)(rgb)) >> 8))
#define GetBValue(rgb)      (LOBYTE((rgb)>>16))

In GDI they didn't want to care about where to store the result, so they provided only basic macros for compounding and extraction and GDI+ just followed this.
Otherwise in GDI version they would have to handle extra value to store/extract/update the result. Avoiding this seems to be reasonable.
It is pity that GDI+ blindly followed the API having class wrapper with the stored value.

Yes there are perfomance considerations (GDI is slow). Just use GetBitmapBits  this will return you a void* which you can cast to a pointer to an ARGB struct of your own. e.g. struct { std::uint8_t a;  std::uint8_t r; std::uint8_t g; std::uint8_t b;} (the actual order might depend on your bitmap format).

@PepijnKramer Ignoring the obvious that this question is about GDI+ (not the GDI), what, exactly, makes your proposed ARGB struct any faster than the DWORD type alias for GDI+' ARGB?

@IInspectable I think that's becuase I answered from memory (I have not used GDI+ for a long  long time). So I forgot about the DWORD alias. The struct is there for convenience so you don't have to bitmask/shift to get individual components out

@PepijnKramer, actually I use these functions only when performance is not the key; otherwise I use direct access to memory bitmap in case I can't use DirectX/DirectDraw/etc. So, I get the answer about performance, but I am still curious why it allows all get functions (if performance is a concern) and still allows SetValue with the same issue with the performance? Are you saying that reading won't cause performance issues you idea is different?

@PepijnKramer, I believe, I found the answer, please see the update section of my question. GDI didn't have place to store the value and GDI+ having it just blindly followed the API. Seems this is the only reasonable explanation, since performance consideration for in-memory copy of pixel shouldn't have much impact when we have a class which could handle variable changes.


[A]m I missing some straightforward way to access the Color components?

No. The individual color channels are exposed for read access only.

If not, what could be the reason of such a design? Is this a kind of compatibility or performance considerations?

With certainty, this can only be answered by the author of the Color class. Since I am not I can only speculate:

Compatibility is likely why the initial class design never received an update. Evolving a C++ class1 under the constraint of maintaining a stable ABI is incredibly challenging.
Performance considerations probably didn't play a role in the design.
Layout compatibility with the in-memory representation of an ARGB value, on the other hand, was a driving factor in modeling the class. Its sole data member (Argb) is a type-alias for a DWORD. There aren't any virtual functions, so casting a DWORD* holding 32bpp pixel data to a Color* is supported.
Given the design to store the color data as a single DWORD value makes it impossible to provide a color channel accessor for write access (BYTE& Color::GetAlpha() would be broken for the same reason that bool& vector<bool>::operator[](size_type) is).

Regardless of whether the above is correct, Color ships the way it does. If you need to set an individual color channel you'll need to implement this functionality yourself. Your proposed implementation is valid, although I'd opt for a different approach:
inline Color SetAlpha(Color src, BYTE alpha) {
    return Color(alpha, src.GetR(), src.GetG(), src.GetB());
}

This avoids a reference so the compiler won't need to optimize reads and writes through a pointer. The size of a Color object is exactly 4 bytes so it conveniently fits into a (sub-)register.
With the entirety of the Color class (implicitly) inline-d (see the <gdipluscolor.h> header), the compiler has everything it needs to evaluate its entire set of optimizations.

1 GDI+ is unique. To my knowledge, it is the only API that shipped with a C++ interface (on top of the flat, C-style API).

Thank you for the detailed answer. I’ve updated my question with the Update section which, I believe, explains the cause. GDI macros were intended for direct work with video memory (or at least, in-memory bitmap) while GDI+ works with the class member which in most cases located in RAM. So, I believe, they just blindly followed the API, forgetting that the situation and purpose has changed. I could be wrong here.

I am not sure that in-memory representation and conversions were really the concern when they designed the class, they just blindly copied API. Otherwise they would have Color(IN ARGB argb) constructor explicit at least, since it frames the developer which calls it for constructing from COLORREF without alpha which makes the resulting Color transparent by default in opposite to the documentation and developer’s expectations.

Not sure about your comment “GDI+ is unique. To my knowledge, it is the only API that shipped with a C++ interface (on top of the flat, C-style API)”. What about MFC, WTL, ATL in some terms. Most of C++ frameworks are developed on top of C-style WINAPI/GDI, etc. Do I miss some point?
